# How to jumble up letters from two strings, in turn of each letter

Tags: python

Turns out to be an extension, to do this. For example:
"hello world" becomes "hweolrllod", where it is the 1st letter from hello, the 1st from world and so on.

Answer (score 6):

If the two words are of same length, you can use `zip`:

```
''.join(x for p in zip(*"hello world".split(" ")) for x in p)
# 'hweolrllod'

''.join(x for p in zip("hello", "world") for x in p)
# 'hweolrllod'
```

If they are not of the same length, and you want to keep the longer version, use [zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

```
from itertools import zip_longest    
''.join(x for p in zip_longest(*"he world".split(" "), fillvalue='') for x in p)
# 'hweorld'

''.join(x for p in zip_longest("he", "world", fillvalue='') for x in p)
# 'hweorld'
```

Comment: Nice answer, I upvoted it, but it would be more understandable if you used more descriptive variables, as in `''.join(char for pair in zip(*"hello world".split(" ")) for char in pair)`.

Comment: Is there any way to move each letter by a certain amount, e.g.

Comment: edit* Is there a way to move each letter by a certain amount e.g. hello world. How do i move the e in hello to the right and by how many. In the simplest form possible please!